# Combine Probability

Tags: probability

I encounter a question:

Janny wakes up early for 2 days on average in a week, excluding Saturday and Sunday. If Janny wakes up early, the probability that she is late to work is 0.3. If Janny does not wake up early, the probability that she is late to work is 0.8.. Janny works 5 days a week except Saturday and Sunday.

If Janny is not late to work, find the probability that she wakes up early on that day.

I tried to solve it by:
(0.7 * 0.4) + 0.2 = 0.48

The answer is 0.7

Any solution or explanation is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you heard of Bayes' Theorem?  Have you heard of conditional probability?  Have you heard of the law of total probability?  This is a routine example of each.

Comment: $0.7\times 0.4$ is the joint probability Janny wakes up early and is not late for work.   What is the joint  probability Janny does not wake up early and is not late for work? (Not $0.2$).  What is the probability Janny is late for work?

Comment: Put another way, in 20 weeks (100 days), how many days do you expect Janny not to be late for work? On how many days do you expect Janny is not late to work and wakes up early on that day?  What proportion of the days that   Janny is not late for work do you expect that Janny wakes up early?

Comment: At first try to notate your events. We can say that we have events $W, L, W^c, L^c$. Event $W$ means that Janny woke up early, event $L$ means that Janny is late to work and we have two events are represented opposite situations. After it try to figure probabilities of which events do you know. For example, we know that $\mathbb{P}[L|W]=0.3$. So you need to recall what is the definition of the conditional probability of event under condition that other event happened.

Answer (score 2):

### Setup:

Let $A$ be the event that Janny woke up early.  Let $B$ be the event that Janny is late to work.

Find and describe each probability given in the problem statement in terms of these events.

> $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{2}{5}, \Pr(B\mid A)=0.3, \Pr(B\mid A^c)=0.8$

You are asked to find $\Pr(A\mid B^c)$

### Calculations:

It would be helpful to find $\Pr(B^c)$.  For that, recall the law of total probability which with $B^c$ as the focus implies that:

$$\Pr(B^c)=\Pr(A\cap B^c)+\Pr(A^c\cap B^c) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B^c\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B^c\mid A^c)$$

Recall also things like how $\Pr(B^c)=1-\Pr(B)$ or that $\Pr(B^c\mid A)=1-\Pr(B\mid A)$ etc...

> $\Pr(B^c)= 0.4\cdot 0.7 + 0.6\cdot 0.2$

Finish by applying Bayes' theorem which for $\Pr(A\mid B^c)$ would be phrased as:

$$\Pr(A\mid B^c)=\dfrac{\Pr(B^c\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B^c)}$$

Just a bit more arithmetic to finish.